# How to get list of all command line argument and forward all of those arguments to another command in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

i have been searched for this issue but didn't found any solution.
Actually i want to create a Compiled in C, and if i enter ant argument to that file then it forwards the argument to another command via system()
Let me explain,
suppose, growkl is my C compiled file.
and in terminal, i wrote this :

```
growkl TRYNEW /etc/cron.d ./grill/mk
```

and then, the growkl file will forward all these arguments ( TRYNEW /etc/cron.d ./grill/mk ) to the command **/usr/bin/gkbroot**
In this way :

```
/usr/bin/gkbroot TRYNEW /etc/cron.d ./grill/mk
```

I'm a newbie with these things, so I'm not getting how to do this.
Can anyone tell me

Comment: Command line arguments are passed to main as strings in argv.  You can pass them directly to the command you want to call using execvp.

Answer (score 0):

if you have your main function thusly:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

then argc is the number of command line arguments and argv[] is an array of strings that represent the arguments.  Notably argv[0] is the command name (usually).

You'll want to use one of the execv  (man execv) variants like:

```
execv(path-of-other-exe, argv)
```

NB: you should make sure that argv ends with a NULL pointer (I think it does from main())... and you can create a new argv with modified arguments, but I don't think it's kosher to modify argv in place.

But in your case, I'm wondering if you just want a symlink (command ln -s /usr/bin/gkbroot growkl)

Comment: You are correct that `argv` is an array of pointers where the next pointer after the last argument is `NULL` as a sentinel. You may want to use `&argv[1]` as the argument to `execv` to avoid passing the current program name as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

To use `system(command)`, you need to build the `command` string with the options from the command line arguments *concatenated* into a single string. For instance, if you want to pass all arguments as arguments to `/usr/bin/gkbroot` using `system()`, you will need to declare a buffer (character array) large enough to hold `"/usr/bin/gkbroot"` plus a `space` between each argument and the *nul-terminating* character.

You can do that by initializing your buffer to `"/usr/bin/gkbroot"` and then looping over each argument, adding a `space` and then the argument to your buffer (after validating that sufficient storage exists in your `command` buffer). For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char command[MAXC] = "/usr/bin/gkbroot";
    size_t len = strlen (command);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        size_t arglen = strlen (argv[i]);
        if (len + arglen + 2 > MAXC) {
            fputs ("error: arguments exceed command storage.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        strcat (command, " ");
        strcat (command, argv[i]);
        len += arglen + 1;
    }
    
    printf ("system (%s)\n", command);
    // system (command);
}
```

(**note:** the actual `system(command);` is currently commented out. To execute the actual command, uncomment the line)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/system_command TRYNEW /etc/cron.d ./grill/mk
system (/usr/bin/gkbroot TRYNEW /etc/cron.d ./grill/mk)
```

This will work regardless of how many arguments you provide, so long as they will fit in `command`, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/system_command arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6
system (/usr/bin/gkbroot arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6)
```

Let me know if that is what you intended and if you have any further questions.